# How to tell which JSON object is being used (Crockford's or another)?

Tags: javascript, json, version

I'm using [Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford)'s [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). When I want to stringify, I do `JSON.stringify()`...works great.

However, those who've taken a look at the code know that it defers to existing JSON objects and properties. I suspect a certain problem I'm having may be due to this deference.

Is there a property of the JSON object I can check to see if the browser is using Crockford's object, or some other? It would be nice to be able to do something like `alert(JSON.version());`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that either all JSON objects are Crockford's implementation or none of them are? If it is, then you could check for the JSON global object before introducing Crockford's script, set a global variable like `nativeJSON = false;` that you could reference later in your code.

Comment: Also, +1 for pointing out this handy script!

Comment: @davidkennedy85, I believe (but don't know) that many browsers these days have native JSON objects in their javascript implementation...I think. I dunno; outta my league.

Comment: I thought the whole point of using the library was for browsers that don't natively support JSON. Crockford's script only creates a new JSON global if there isn't one there already. Otherwise I would imagine it does nothing.

Comment: *Otherwise I would imagine it does nothing.* But, @david, isn't that the point of the question? Crockfords implementation might yield different results to other implementations, so one might want to know which one is used?

Comment: @davidkennedy85, yes, but since I have no idea of who will visit the site and what browser they use, I load the Crockford object. But, of course, it checks and defers to anything already defined in the browser. Not sure how to tell if the browser's using a native (or other) JSON object, or the Crockford one I told it to load. Hmmmm.

Comment: This is an interesting question in itself, but why don't you post another about the specific problem you mentioned?

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes, I will in the morning (too late here). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can decide one to use like this:

```
<script>window.JSON || document.write('<script src="js/json2.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

This checks for `window.JSON` (supported by browser) first if it exists, use that else imports json2.js of Crockford.

## update

```
var whichJSON = null;

if (! window.JSON) {
  document.write('<script src="js/json2.js"><\/script>');
  whichJSON = 'Crockford Version';
}
else {
  whichJSON = 'Browser Native Version';
}

alert(whichJSON);
```

Comment: This is very elegant, but it doesn't make it any easier to check later in the code which implementation is being used.

Comment: @davidkennedy85: Yep I wont worry about which version since the purpose would be to use JSON whichever available :)

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't answer the question :)

Comment: But how can I use this method to tell whether I'm using an existing JSON object or Crockford's? I'd like say so in an alert at minimum, and at maximum it would be nice to be able to make programmatic decisions based on whether it's Crockford or other.

Answer (score 3):

Before you load Crockford's script, you can check for the global JSON object exactly like he does:

```
<script>
    var JSON,
        nativeJSON = true;

    if (!JSON) {
        var nativeJSON = false;
        document.write('<script src="js/json2.js"><\/script>');
    }

    if (!nativeJSON) {
        // All JSON objects are using Crockford's implementation
    } else {
        // All JSON objects from here on out are NOT using Crockford's implementation
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not [*all*](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), I think?

Comment: Do scripts loaded via the `src` attribute execute in the order sequenced on the page each and every time? I wouldn't want the check to occur after json2.js was loaded.

Comment: That's a good point. @Sarfraz posted a solution that I will borrow.

Comment: @JonathanM - Yes, scripts included via "standard" script element syntax will be executed in the order they are included. (There are ways to load and execute scripts asynchronously, but it wouldn't happen by accident.)

Comment: Your condition `!JSON` refers to `JSON` variable declared on top not the native browser json object

Comment: @Sarfraz, it would seem so, but Crockford does the exact same thing.

Comment: @Sarfraz, JSON declared globally and window.JSON are the same. See [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#activation_object_variable_object), or just trying adding a check to see if `JSON === window.JSON` to the script above.

Comment: IE8 (and up?) loads scripts [in parallel](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?ex=3&title=IE8+Parallel+Script+Loading), but like @nnnnnn says I've also always assumed that execution is still done in the order they are defined.